# how to upload and read csv file in django using csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, django, csv

I am reading csv file through upload and trying to store all values in a list

```
def upload(request):
    paramFile = request.FILES['file'].read()
    data = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
    list1 = []
    for row in data:
        list1.append(row)

    print list1
```

*file.csv*

```
12345,abcdef
```

*output*

```
[{'1': '', None: ['']}, {'1': '2'}]
```

I want to append all values in `list1`

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it `[{12345: 'abcdef'}]`?

Comment: And? What's the question here?

Comment: i want final list to be as list1 = ['12345', 'abcdef']

Comment: I see nothing having to do with dictionaries, so why are you using `DictReader`?

Comment: @shashisp are you sure you don't want a list of lists: `[['12345', 'abcdef'], ...]`?  One for each line in the CSV?

Comment: @JamieCockburn even list of lists is okay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You are passing a string to the constructor of `DictReader`.  You must pass an iterable object that gives the individual lines in the input (a string is iterable, but will give each character one at a time).  Luckily, an [`UploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) object (like those in the `FILES` dictionary) are already file-like objects that support iteration, so just do this:

  ```
  data = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['file'])
  ```
- Your input data only has one line.  `DictReader` will use that line for the column "headers", which will become the key in the resulting dictionaries.  You will then have no data left!  It looks like you don't want a `DictReader`, just a regualar [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

  ```
  data = csv.reader(request.FILES['file'])
  ```

Answer (score 48):

This should work if you're using Python 3.

```
file = request.FILES['file'] 
decoded_file = file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
reader = csv.DictReader(decoded_file)
for row in reader:
    # Get each cell value based on key-value pair. 
    # Key will always be what lies on the first row.
```

We can use the list that `splitlines()` creates. `splitlines()` is called because `csv.DictReader` expects "*any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its **next**() method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable*".

Comment: nice note on the decoded_file variable. This had me stumped all afternoon and that line helped, thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to read some CSV inside a django model textarea, splitlines() will also do the trick!

Answer (score 17):

in Python 3, to get the correct type (String not bytes) without reading the full file into memory you can use a generator to decode line by line:

```
def decode_utf8(input_iterator):
    for l in input_iterator:
        yield l.decode('utf-8')

def upload(request):
    reader = csv.DictReader(decode_utf8(request.FILES['file']))
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Or using generator expression: `reader = csv.DictReader(chunk.decode() for chunk in request.FILES['file'])`

Comment: What if the chunking algorithm splits apart a multi-byte UTF-8 character? This would cause a UnicodeDecodeError.