# Reading CSV in Python/Django - Weird Mapping for csvDict

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to read a csv file line-by-line in my views.py file. The csv file is structured as follows:

xk, ab, cd

11, 20, 30

31, 27, 35

etc

```
if request.method == "POST":
    pdb.set_trace()
    form = FormName(request.POST, request.FILES)
    file = request.FILES['csv'].read()
    if form.is_valid():       
        try:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for row in reader:
                xk = row['xk']
```

Before executing the last line above, when I print 'row' in pdb, I get {'x': 'k'}. However, I should get "11, 20, 30" (or something similar with that data, since DictReader is supposed to automatically use the first line as a header. When I print the file in pdb I get:

'xk,ab,cd\n11,20,30\n31,27,35' etc. How can I properly read the csv file?

Comment: i'm not sure about the `request.FILES['csv'].read()`, open the file inside a `with open` statement is not an option ?

Comment: with open was being problematic, which is why I used .read(). There are several threads on this :/

Comment: (I get this error: TypeError: 'coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found')

Comment: try the same without the `.read()` method, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704630/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-in-django-using-csv-dictreader)

Comment: `request.FILES['csv']` returns an UploadedFile object, that seems to fit your dictReader approach

Comment: ^^That worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resolved in comments:
>
> try the same without the `.read()` method, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704630/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-in-django-using-csv-dictreader) – PRMoureu
>
> `request.FILES['csv']` returns an UploadedFile object, that seems to fit your dictReader approach – PRMoureu
>
> ^^That worked. Thanks!! – user7518095