# Django how to upload CSV file using Form to populate postgres database and display all items in browser

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-forms, django-file-upload

Django 3.2.1, Python 3.6, Postgres database

EDITED to take into account comments below, thanks!

I am writing a small Django app for storing product information. I coded the backend logic for uploading a local `csv` file using a `Custom Management Command` and am connecting this to the front end.

I am having trouble implementing the file upload -> having user upload `products.csv` via a `Form` submission to populate the database with file and display all products on one page.

I have stripped down my previous examples, as well as the suggested code below, to the simplest format to try to locate the problem.

Example of the `csv` file:

```
name,sku,description
Brian James,skus-look-like-this,The products will have various descriptions. And multiple lines too.
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    status = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default='inactive')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product'
```

Form for individual `product` CRUD operations and for CSV file upload.

**forms.py**

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':
        'Upload "products.csv"', 'help_text': 'Choose a .csv file with products to enter'}))
```

**/templates/upload.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="sent_file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
# Function to upload the form, parse it, save to database
def create_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UploadForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})

    # If not GET method then proceed
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print('FIRST FORM', form)

    # Validate the form
    if form.is_valid():
            csv_file = form.cleaned_data['csv_file']
            # Errors begin here ^, print(csv_file) = 'None'

            form.save()
            # Crashes here ^ with error: "AttributeError: 'UploadForm' object has no attribute 'save'
"
            file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, form.csv_file.url)
            # printing `file_path` = `AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'url'
`
        
            # read the file contents and save the product details
            with open(f'{file_path}, r') as products_csv:

            products_file = csv.reader(products_csv)
            next(products_file)  # skip header row

            for counter, line in enumerate(products_file):

                name = line[0]
                sku = line[1]
                description = line[2]

                p = Product()
                p.name = name
                p.sku = sku
                p.description = description
                p.status = random.choice(['active', 'inactive'])
                p.save()

    return redirect('/show_product')
```

Changing `form.cleaned_data['csv_file']` to `request.FILES['sent_file']` correctly prints the file name `uploads.csv` but the `url` is still inaccessible and still crashes on `form.save()`. The only way I can print to terminal the contents of the uploaded file is by adding this:

```
csv_file = request.FILES['sent_file']
for i in csv_file:
    print(i)
```

outputs:

```
b"'name','sku','description'\n"
b"'Zed','some-skus-more','descriptions. galore.'\n"
```

But the file still can't be uploaded and `form.save()` can't be implemented.

I'm not sure how to continue debugging this. If anyone can point me in the right direction, would really appreciate it!

Comment: Change this part of the uploadcsv function " if not  csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):"  to 
 if not csv_file.customer_name.endswith('.csv'): i am suspecting our error stems from there !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704630/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-in-django-using-csv-dictreader/24704808) I was able to find an answer by using a generator to decode the CSV line by line.

Here is the code:
**views.py**

```
def decode_utf8(line_iterator):
    for line in line_iterator:
        yield line.decode('utf-8')


    
def create_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UploadForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})

    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    # Validate the form
    if form.is_valid():

        # Get the correct type string instead of byte without reading full file into memory with a generator to decode line by line
        products_file = csv.reader(decode_utf8(request.FILES['sent_file']))
        next(products_file)  # Skip header row

        for counter, line in enumerate(products_file):
            name = line[0]
            sku = line[1]
            description = line[2]

            p = Product()
            p.name = name
            p.sku = sku
            p.description = description
            p.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Saved successfully!')

        return redirect('/show_product')
```

Answer (score 1):

In other to save CSV files you will create a function to read the csv file and save product details: but you can as well refactor the code to meet your suit.

- Upload and save the file first using Product()
- Get the path for the file and read the contents
  It would be better if you have the same names for model fields and csv columns
- Loop through each line and create a dictionary which contains only a product details at an iteration
- Make an instance of Product() and pass the dictionary to it and save
- For the foreign key, get the object from Product() using get() accordingly with the value that is stored in csv

```
# You could save the Product details in two ways

new_product = Product()
new_product.registration_number = fields[0]
new_product.customer_name = fields[1] # Change this field name the customer
# like so for other fields

new_product.save()
.....
# Create a model object, create a dictionary of key values where keys corresponds to the field names of the model.

# create a dictionary `new_product_details` containing values of a product

new_product = Product()
new_product.__dict__.update(new_product_details)
new_product.save()

import csv
def save_new_product_from_csv(file_path):
    # do try catch accordingly
    # open csv file, read lines
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        products = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
        row = 0
        for product in products:
            if row==0:
                headers = product
                row = row + 1
            else:
                # create a dictionary of product details
                new_product_details = {}
                for i in range(len(headers)):
                    new_product_details[headers[i]] = product[i]

                # for the foreign key field you should get the object first and reassign the value to the key
                #We will also have to change the product name to customer_name get the foreign key value
                new_product_details['customer_name'] = Product.objects.get() # get the record according to value which is stored in db and csv file

                # create an instance of product model
                new_product = Product()
                new_product.__dict__.update(new_product_details)
                new_product.save()
                row = row + 1
        fp.close()
```

Your code should look something like this after:

```
def uploadcsv(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UploadForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form':form})

    # If not GET method then proceed
    try:
        form = UploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            csv_file = form.cleaned_data['csv_file']
            if not csv_file.customer_name.endswith('.csv'):
                messages.error(request, 'File is not CSV type')
                return redirect('/show_product')
            # If file is too large
            if csv_file.multiple_chunks():
                messages.error(request, 'Uploaded file is too big (%.2f MB)' %(csv_file.size(1000*1000),))
                return redirect('/show_product')

            # save and upload file 
            form.save()

            # get the path of the file saved in the server
            file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, form.csv_file.url)

            # a function to read the file contents and save the product details
            save_new_product_from_csv(file_path)
            # do try catch if necessary
                
    except Exception as e:
        logging.getLogger('error_logger').error('Unable to upload file. ' + repr(e))
        messages.error(request, 'Unable to upload file. ' + repr(e))
    return redirect('/show_product')
```

Adding a customer name attribute to your model like so:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    status = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default='inactive')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product'
```

Comment: Thanks! I integrated the above code into `views.py` but the same problem appears: file is NoneType. `messages` = ```Unable to upload file. AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'")```                                                                                                                    After the line `form = UploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)` I printed both inputs: `request.POST` = `request.POST <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['***']}>` `.FILES` = `<MultiValueDict: {'media': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: uploads.csv (text/csv)>]}>`.

Comment: Any other ideas of how to get the file uploaded properly?

Comment: I suggest you add a customer name  attribute to the Product model  as Foreign Key. then apply it in this fields new_product.customer_name = fields[1], new_product_details['customer_name'] = Product.objects.get(),

Comment: I made some edits of my post by adding the customer attribute to the product model and then applying them to the fields. hopefully we should be able to save csv.

Comment: Thanks for the update! This isn't working either. Regardless of the fields in `models.py`, something about the upload process isn't working. I've looked over all the html docs which look fine but the .csv keeps coming up empty and can't be processed.

Comment: it wasn't only the model field that i updated, I  made update to the save_new_product_from_csv function as well please kindly find time to copy and try it, if  throw any  exception  copy and share it so that i can kindly have a look and help solve your challenge! Thank you !

Comment: I have updated my code to be identical to yours and am receiving this error "Unable to upload file. AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'")". I am going to try to simplify my code above to hone in to the problem and will post it above shortly. Thanks for your help, I am looking forward to solving this challenge! :)

Comment: I've updated the code with the simplest example. Thanks for taking another look!